# generate random string so no two threads collide

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, random, uniqueidentifier

Here is the code for my random string generator

```
private static string GetUniqueKey()
{
    int maxSize  = 15 ;
    char[] chars = new char[62];
    string a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    chars = a.ToCharArray();
    int size  = maxSize ;
    byte[] data = new byte[1];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider  crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data) ;
    size =  maxSize ;
    data = new byte[size];
    crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(size) ;
    foreach(byte b in data )
    {
        result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length - 1)]);
    }
    return result.ToString();

}
```

How do I write a unit test that would test for 100% guarantee that no 2 threads will generate the same random number

I don't want to lock thread because it creates performance night mare under extreme load tests.

This logic will be used in load balanced 8 app servers.

I can't use GUID because this random string should be humanly readable like a credit card number.

Do I have to constantly read database to ensure that this is a unique number before I store in DB?

Comment: How about Guid.NewGuid?

Comment: When using a randomiser without a singleton or a lock thread controlling the randomiser you can not: The definition of random is such that you get a random value from a defined (however extremely large) set. You can only influence the chance on not getting the same random value by making your base set from which you are generating the random values is sufficiently large.

Comment: even with large set, how do I ensure that this is unique in DB?

Comment: You said "I can't use GUID because this random string should be humanly readable like a credit card number", so you may process a checksum on the GUID and provide its hexadecimal encoding. Alternatively, why don't you concatenate a server unique ID with an incremental number set by each server ?

Comment: Side note: the fact that you want guarantee that every 2 random number are unique guarantees that these are *not random* numbers.

Comment: why do you think GUID's are not human readable? Don't overthink the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. How it is related to threads?
2. > > I just want to make sure that the number is unique so that its not stored in the database twice.

There are different ways to do it:

a. Loading all the keys from db to a list and then query the list
I don't really like this way but if it is a small list, it is better that query the DB each time.

b. Reading each time from DB, it depends if the DB is local or not.

c. Having an internal mechanism that will generate new unique keys according to the last one saved in DB. FOr example, if the last saved key is AAA, so you know that the next one will be AAB. Just an idea

d. Define this unique key as Primary key, if you will try to add the same key, you will get an exception --> Having try catch may help.
I don't really like it since it can also affect the performance.

I was going on b or c.
Maybe there are additionals solutions, try to see what is better for you according to the requirements/needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have n working threads. You should have a shared set of strings and a center thread to handle that set. The life cycle should look like this:

1. A working thread generates a string. If it is already present in the queue, then repeat this step, until you get a new string.
2. When you have a new string which is not present in the set, the working thread should add it into the set as a candidate.
3. Your center thread should check the candidates. If a given candidate is duplicated in the set, then mark them as duplicates. If they are not duplicates in the set, then check them against the database. If it is duplicate, then mark it as duplicate. If not, then mark it as successful. Notify the worker threads behind those values.
4. A notified worker thread should mark the value as acknowledged and if the value was duplicated, then jump to step 1.
5. The center thread should handle the acknowledged elements and remove them from the set.

It is a good idea to have a few elements cached in the center thread to reduce the probability of needing to process the database in case the value was duplicated.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is it related to threads?

I mean, if you may get the same number in 2 different threads, you may got it also in a non-parallel scenario.
Getting a same number is not related to thread.
BTW, you could use Guid.NewGuid() to get a unique key.

Comment: this random string should be human readable so I can not use GUID

Comment: I just want to make sure that the number is unique so that its not stored in the database twice.